# What about the boundness of this operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H^{+}\subset H\subset H^{-}$ be three embedded and dense Hilbert spaces and let $A$ denote a linear operator with domain $D(A)$. Let $\eta\in\mathbb{R}, \eta\neq 0$ and suppose that
$$A -i\eta\in H.$$
Furthermore, for every $v\in H^{+}$, $v = Bu$ with $B$ operator and $u\in H$, suppose to have 
$$(A -i\eta) v = u.$$
If the operator $B$ is bounded from $H^{-}$ to $H^{+}$, why we can say that $(A-i\eta)^{-1}$ is bounded on $H$ to itself?

This is written on my notes, but I don't understand why it is true. Could someone please help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: by construction for all $u\in H$,
$$(A-i\eta)^{-1}u=Bu. $$
Take norms in $H$ then use the continuity of the embeddings and of $B$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! If I take the norms, then $\Vert (A-i\eta)^{-1} u\Vert = \Vert Bu\Vert$ and since $B$ is bounded from $H^{-}$ in $H^{+}$ I have $\Vert B(H)^{-}\Vert_{H^{+}}\leq c_2$. Finally, using the embedding $H^{+}\subset H$, I conclude that taken $u\in H$, it follows $\Vert(A-i\eta)^{-1} u\Vert_{H} = \Vert Bu\Vert_{H}\leq c\Vert Bu\Vert_{H^{+}}\leq c_2$. Did you mean this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by $\|B(H)^-\|_{H^+}\leq c_2$. you should get $\|Bu\|_{H^+}\leq \|B\| \|u\|_{H^-}\leq c\|B\| \|u\|_H$. Other than that, yes.